# Gunicorn to disable timeout

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn

I am using Gunicorn to serve my flask webapp. My web app sends requests to download huge files some more than 10GB, which takes a while to complete. I am streaming the output of the progress back to the webpage using a generator, so the connection is left open until the download is done. My problem is Gunicorn will timeout after a certain amount of seconds.

I configured the timeout to be longer like this:

```
/usr/bin/gunicorn -c /my/dir/to/app/gunicorn.conf -b 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi --timeout 90
```

but I don't know how long it will take, so I have to keep changing this timeout if the downloaded file gets larger and larger.

I was wondering if there is a way to disable the timeout all together, or if there is another option to remedy long download times.

Comment: Value is a positive number or 0. Setting it to 0 has the effect of infinite timeouts by disabling timeouts for all workers entirely.

Answer (score 4):

The timeout setting you specify with Gunicorn is to basically release a connection and restart a worker. Gunicorn kills such idle workers and restarts them. [[1]](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout)

If you are streaming back the response, then IMO, your worker shouldn't get knocked off and killed by the parent process. Note, a connection is idle if no data is sent or received by a host.

So now here is what you might want to try. These are my personal suggestions.

- Use `--threads` settings, and set it up to a greater than 1 value; in this way, your worker may not be sitting idle and could be serving other requests. [[2]](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#threads)
- Instead of specifying a timeout here, you could try providing a timeout in the request's header. For this, you need to understand the `Keep-Alive` header. The Keep-Alive has a `timeout` parameter. [[3]](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/learning-about-the-http-connection-keep-alive-header-7ebe0efa209d) and [[4]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive)
- Use `multi-part` download to speed up your downloading of the large file. For this, you need to break-down the download into chunks, and then you could issue parallel requests for downloading that large file. [[5]](https://medium.com/@suvanika/multipart-download-and-byte-ranges-b5d6b7577e95)
- Since your objective seems to be that you want to stream back the progress of your download back on a webpage, so instead of keeping the connection alive and open, using polling technique to fetch the progress of your download. Poll after every, say, 250-400 ms to get an update. In this way, your system would be more robust on slow-network connections also, and scalable for arbitrary large files. The caveat is that you need to somehow maintain the information of how much file has been downloaded. I personally built a multi-part download manager in Scala, using Actor framework.
- One more suggestion is that you might also want to try a library like Flask-SocketIO. And although this is not really a bidirectional communication, but the point is to ensure that the socket remains open to give back the progress update. [[6]](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)